# What is the function of a capacitor between source and gate in this reverse polarity protection circuit?

Tags: circuit-protection, component-selection, reverse-polarity

I want to incorporate a simple reverse polarity protection to my design. I stumbled across this circuit in the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 IO Board schematic:

[image: schematic]

I understand how the Q1 + D4 + R26 combo works, but what is the function of C40?

Comment: I’m not sure this is the main purpose, but you can imagine that as the +12V starts to come up the capacitor will tend to switch the FET quickly to fully conducting, and the reverse at switch-off.

Comment: When the power jack is inserted correctly, the body diode of the MOSFET will cause the 12V rail to rise quickly, and after a short delay, R26 will activate the gate of Q1. There could be a problem if the input is quickly reversed before C40 discharges, and reverse polarity might briefly be passed through the MOSFET before it fully turns off. This condition might persist until the 12V rail discharges, which could take a while depending on load.